# Print ArrayList data using Stream

Tags: stream

I am using below code, but it does not prints the list member  line by line, rather prints the entire list.
ArrayList aList=new ArrayList<>();

```
    aList.add("Pink");
    aList.add("Green");
    aList.add("Red");
    aList.add("Yellow");

    Stream.of(aList).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

output that i get
[Pink, Green, Red, Yellow]

I require to print each of these elements in a new line.

Comment: got the solution

aList.stream().parallel().forEach(s ->System.out.println(s));

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this :

```
aList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

`Stream.of(T... values)` takes an array as parameter, for Collections you can call the `forEach` method directly on the instance (like above).